# Google Cloud projects merging

Tags: google-cloud-platform

very sorry for a probably stupid and a not very detailed question, but nonetheless, here's the situation:

I have two google cloud projects, one is quite old and only has Google Maps API oauth application, while the second one is the one my organisation uses. the second project has all the needed API oauth tokens, so the question is - is it somehow possible to transfer the GoogleMaps API token from one project to another? 
I see both of the projects under one login, so they're kinda together, but at the same time they have different functionality, so i'd like to somehow merge them both - is it possible?

Google FAQ doesn't seem to cover this question, so stackoverflow is my last chance to try and find out.

Lots of thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Google Cloud Projects cannot be merged together. You will need to recreate the resources in the other project.

Comment: that's a pity.
am i getting it right - i can simply add a new project and recreate the resources all together in it, but will i have to gain access to the resources like i'm adding them the very first time? i mean the verification for example.

Comment: You are recreating the resources, so yes, you will have to manage them like the first time. Moving resources between projects is not supported.

Comment: John, many thanks, you've saved me a lot of time.
cheers.

Comment: John, a few questions here, hope you have an answer - 
what if i just add the Google Maps API token to the second project - will i have to complete the verification for the whole project again? 
or if i add a new project to handle all of the API tokens - meanwhile, will the other 2 be functioning properly?

Comment: Your comment does not have enough details, so my reply is "I am not sure". Create a new question for each item with details. Remember that projects are independent. If a service requires verification, you will need to re-verify in each project. API tokens are project specific and you should switch to OAuth tokens (User credentials or service accounts) for most services today.